# How to replace a String starting with $ character using Java's String.replaceAll method

Tags: java, regex, string

What's the correct regex for a String starting with $ char as the first argument (i.e. the string to replace) to Java's replaceAll method in the String class? I can't get the syntax right.
Example

```
String s = "SUMIF($C$6:$C$475,\"   India - Hyd\",K$6:K$475)";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("$475", "$44"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\$475", "\\$44"));
```

Comment: Any suggestions for replacement of first occurrence only?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest in this case you use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of `replaceAll()`, because you're not using any regex:

```
System.out.println(s.replace("$475", "$44"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of [`string.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)  states that

> public String replace(CharSequence target,
>                CharSequence replacement)
>
> Replaces `each` substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

So you can use `replace` method instead of replaceAll.

```
String s = "SUMIF($C$6:$C$475,\"   India - Hyd\",K$6:K$475)";
System.out.println(s.replace("$475", "$44"));
```